# «Видный ученый-правовед» — через дефис?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, запятые, приложение, дефис

*Видный ученый-правовед, успешно трудившийся над разработкой отрасли международного права, П.Е. Казанский писал...*
(После "писал" двоеточие и цитата.)

Comment: С учётом того, что «Правовед, муж. 1. Ученый, специалист по праву», то конструкция с дефисом тянет на тавтологию.  Союз предпочтительнее, или зпт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с общего правила (Розенталь):

> **2.** Одиночное нераспространенное приложение [правовед], стоящее после нарицательного существительного [ученый], обособляется, если определяемое существительное имеет при себе пояснительные слова, например: *Он остановил коня, поднял голову и увидал своего корреспондента, дьякона* (Тургенев); *Ухаживала за мной одна девушка, полька* (Горький).

Тогда пишем так: *Видный **ученый, правовед,** успешно трудившийся...*

Но есть интересное **примечание 2**:

> В некоторых случаях возможно дефисное написание и при наличии пояснительного слова (определения), которое по смыслу может относиться или ко всему сочетанию (*известный экспериментатор-изобретатель, ловкий акробат-жонглёр*), или только к определяемому слову (*оригинальный художник-самоучка, моя соседка-педагог*), или только к приложению (*женщина-врач с большим стажем*). Однако в этих случаях обычно возможна двоякая пунктуация; ср.: *Лекцию прочитает известный профессор-химик.* — *Лекцию прочитает известный профессор, химик.*

Это наш случай, можем писать так: *Видный **ученый-правовед,** успешно трудившийся...*

> Однако никто в семье, да и в школе, несмотря на хорошие и отличные оценки, не предчувствовал, что в этом худощавом и симпатичном подростке скрывается **будущий видный ученый-правовед**, которого будет знать вся юридическая Москва и который примет активное участие в разработке Конституции СССР 1977 г.
> К. С. Бельский (из материалов конференции, РГУП, 2015)

**Про инициалы**
Правильно писать их с пробелом: П. Е. Казанский.

**Про тавтологию**
В толковом словаре Кузнецова:
[правовед](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Pravoved-33303.html), -а; *м.*
**1.** Специалист по правоведению, юрист.

В том же словаре Кузнецова: химик — специалист по химии.
Не каждый правовед или химик является ученым. Это может быть преподаватель в школе или техникуме, выпускник вуза, работник полиции или лаборант (никак не ученый).

[Обособленные приложения](http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/rules-rosental/articles/093-obosoblennye-prilozheniya.htm)
[Как писать инициалы имени и отчества?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/78-init)